Angular 17 - can't get to navigate to page and scroll to fragment reference on page
One component has this
Router Link
<span
    [routerLink]="deltaLink() ? '../../' + deltaLink() : null"
    [fragment]="'header-' + headerText()"
    [@fadeInOut] class="material-symbols-outlined delta-found">
    sync_problem
  </span>

Page with fragment link
In the other component, I create the link reference
<div class="rounded-container">

  <div class="header" [attr.id]="'header-' + headerText()">
    <p>{{headerText()}}</p>
  </div>

</div>

My angular set up looks like this so far
App set up
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES,
    {
      scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      anchorScrolling: 'enabled' }
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideAnimations(),
    {provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'outline'}}
],
  }
).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err),
);

I've also tried this
bootstrapApplication(
  AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
    provideRouter(APP_ROUTES,
      {
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled' }
      as RouteReuseStrategy), --> but this bit doesn't work
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimationsAsync(),
    provideAnimations(),
    {provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {appearance: 'outline'}}
],
  }
).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err),
);

Problem
It navigates to the page, but doesn't scroll down to where the fragment is, defined by [attr.id]
Any ideas?
UPDATE
I thought ngAfterContentInit() alone would work, but I had to add a timing delay...and then it worked! Not the most elegant solution, but I can confirm it works.
 ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    // Scroll to anchor fragment after a delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
        console.log(fragment)
        if (fragment) {
          const element = document.getElementById(fragment);
          // Use the found element here
          console.log('Found element:', element);
          if (element) {
            element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest' });
          }
        }
      });
    }, 1000);
  }


It is likely that the element with the scrolling area is nested in the page and not at the root

The linked component referenced by [routerLink]="deltaLink() ? '../../' + deltaLink() is loaded within  of a larger component, but the whole linked component is scrollable (its not nested in something else inside ). I think it might be to do with my ngModule thing, as I'm only using stand alone components and can't / don't know how to configure scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', anchorScrolling: 'enabled', inside providers

You can enable scrolling feature which can be used with withInMemoryScrolling function.
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
      provideRouter(APP_ROUTES, withInMemoryScrolling())
    ]
  }
);


This didn't work. I had to do a timing hack to get it to work...

This works for Angular 17
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent,
  {
    providers: [
      provideRouter(APP_ROUTES, withInMemoryScrolling({
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
      }))
    ]
  }

);

The sole difference between this answer and Chellapan's answer is that values are provided for two parameters to withInMemoryScrolling, where Chellapan relies on the defaults.
